# How to check if any other flash application in same browser is already using the camera?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, camera

I am having two flash applications on a same web page. Lets say one is already accessing the camera, then if i click on the second application, it will directly start using the camera. I dont want this. I need to check if any other flash application is already accessing the camera in the same web page. Let me tell you that we cant use Camera.getCamera() and check if the camera==null, this wont work, since the camera is available. So can you please help me to check if the camera is accessed by the parent browser or any other flex application in the same web page?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you own the web page containing the Flash objects, you could use JavaScript, via `ExternalInterface`, to monitor which camera has been started or not.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `LocalConnection` to make communication directly between the two SWF's.